# How to find $\limsup_{a \to 0} E[V | aV+W]$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

How to find 
\begin{align}
\limsup_{a \to 0} E[V | aV+W]
\end{align}
where $V$ and $W$ are independent. We can assume that $E[V^2], E[W^2] <\infty$.

I think the following must 
\begin{align}
\limsup_{a \to 0} E[V | aV+W]=E[V] \text{ a.s.}
\end{align}

I found this property called martingale convergence that says: If $E[V] <\infty$ then 
\begin{align} 
\lim E[ V | \mathcal{H}_n] \to E[ V | \mathcal{H}]
\end{align}
if $ \mathcal{H}_n$ is a decreasing sequence (nested) of sub-sigma algebrals and $ \mathcal{H}=\cap_n  \mathcal{H}_n$,

But how to apply this? Or this is ever a correct tool to use?

{\bf Edit 1:}
See counter example A.S. Now suppose we assume that $V$ is Gaussian random variable.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X | X=x] = x$, so if you can prove that $\mathbb{E}[a W| V+a W=v+aw] = \mathcal{O}(a)$ then $\mathbb{E}[V | V+a W=v+aw] = \mathbb{E}[V +aW| V+a W=v+aw] - \mathbb{E}[a W| V+a W=v+aw] = v+aw + \mathcal{O}(a)$

Comment: $E(V|V+aW)=V+aW-aE(W|V+aW)\to V$ $a.s$ and in $L^2$.

Comment: $\limsup_{a \to 0} E[V | aV+W]=E[V]$ does not hold. Consider independent Bernoulli $V$ and $W$ to get $E[V | aV+W]=V$ for $a\ne 1$. Or just set $W=0$ for simplicity to get the same result.

Comment: Dear all there was a type. Now corrected. I am interested in $E[V| aV+W]$ and not $E[V| V+aW]$

Comment: @A.S. Thanks for the counter example. I will modify my question to so that $V$ is  Gaussian.

Comment: If you also assume that $W$ is a non-degenerate normal (you need to assume something since otherwise you can set W=constant and get $=V$), then you do get $E(V)$ as the lmit through simple integration of densities.

Comment: If $W$ have density that is everywhere positive, than convergence to $E(V)$ holds.

Comment: @A.S. Do you mind putting all theses case and summarizing this in the answer?