# Application of dominated convergence theorem to conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have the following sequence of random variables such that

\begin{align}
Z_a&=E^2[V^2|aV+W]\\
\lim_{a \to 0} Z_a&= E^2[V^2]  \quad  (a.s.)
\end{align}
where $V$ and $W$ are independent and $W$ is not degenerate.

We want to find the limit 
\begin{align}
\lim_{a \to 0} E[Z_a]=\lim_{a \to 0} E[E^2[V^2|aV+W] ]
\end{align}

We can use Dominated Convergence Theorem  to show the following. Since 
\begin{align}
Z_a= E^2[V^2|aV+W] \le  E[V^4|aV+W]=Y (\text{ by Jensen's inequality })
\end{align}

Moreover, $E[Y]=E[V^4]$ (** here assumed that $E[V^4]<\infty$ **). So by DCT we have that 
\begin{align}
\lim_{a \to 0} E[Z_a]= E[ \lim_{a \to 0} Z_a]=E[E^2[V^2]]=E^2[V^2]
\end{align}

**My question is:** Do we require  the assumption that $E[V^4]<\infty$ to show the above result or can we find the limit with out  this assumption?

This question is somewhat related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631150/how-to-find-limsup-a-to-0-ev-avw).

Thanks for any help.

**Edit (by extrapolating suggestion A.S. )**

Suppose  $f_W(w)$ is bounded, that is $f_W(w) \le a$ then
\begin{align}
E[V^2|aV+W=x]&= \int v^2 \frac{f_{aV+W|V}(x|v)}{f_{aV+W}(x)} dV(v)=\int v^2 \frac{f_{aV+W}(x-av)}{f_{aV+W}(x)} dV(v) \le  \int v^2 \frac{c}{f_{aV+W}(x)} dV(v)\\
& \frac{c}{f_{aV+W}(x)} \int v^2  dV(v)=\frac{c}{f_{aV+W}(x)} E[V^2]\\
\end{align}

So, now
\begin{align}
E[ Z_a] \le E \left[ c^2 E[V^2] \frac{1}{(f_{aV+W}(aV+W))^2} \right]=c^2 E[V^2] E \left[  \frac{1}{(f_{aV+W}(aV+W))^2} \right]
\end{align}

But what to do with the term $E \left[  \frac{1}{(f_{aV+W}(aV+W))^2} \right]$??

Comment: It's not enough for $W$ to be non-degenerate.It's sufficient for $W$ to have everywhere positive density and it might be sufficient to have $supp(W)=R$ only.

Comment: @A.S. Ok. Suppose we assume that $W$ has positive density everywhere. Is assumption $E[V^4]< \infty$ necessary ? Or can we do with out it?

Comment: What is $E^2$ in $E^2[V^2|aV+W]$ and $E^2[V^2]$?

Comment: @Did  expectation squared. That is $E^2[V^2] =(E[V^2])^2$

Comment: If density of $W$ is bounded, you don't need any extra conditions for convergence.

Comment: @A.S thanks. I see it now. I will put what you suggested as an edit. Could check whether it is what you had in mind.

Comment: $E(V^2|aV+W=x)=\frac{\int v^2f_V(v)f_W(x-av)\, dv}{\int f_V(v)f_W(x-av)\,dv}$. The numerator is bounded by $aE(V^2)<\infty$ and the denominator converges to $f_W(x)>0$.

Comment: @A.S. Yes, I see that. But how to  work with the term $ \lim_{a \to 0} E[ \frac{1}{ (\int f_v(v) f_w(x-av) dv )^2}]$. Is dominating convergence theorem ?